# Reading file line by line in Bash expands special characters

Tags: bash, readline

I'm parsing some `.html` files in Bash. I read the input with:

```
while read line 
do
   echo $line
   ...do something...
done < $file
```

Now I've expierenced something real strange. Some lines in the files contain something like

```
Resolution…: 720 * 576
```

But bash gives me this:

```
Resolution…: 720 mysript.sh another_script.pl 576
```

Bash expands the `* char` to the content of the actual directory. How can I read the text line by line without expanding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the expanding happens in `echo`, not in `read`, you should quote your output:

```
echo "$line"
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I've been blind

Comment: This answer is incorrect!
For "sourceFile" containing "RewriteRule ^(.*)\.[\d]{10}\.(css|js)$ $1.$2 [L]"

cat sourceFile | while read line; do echo "${line}" produces
RewriteRule ^(.*).[d]{10}.(css|js)$ $1.$2 [L]    WRONG
whereas the same command with read -r line produces 
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.[\d]{10}\.(css|js)$ $1.$2 [L] CORRECT

Comment: @catwalk -my apologies - as per the below I've conflated 2 things so probably both answers are correct

Answer (score 5):

you should read your file like this, with the -r option

```
while read -r line 
do
   echo "$line"
   #..do something...
done < "$file"
```

Comment: This is a good practice, but it solves a different problem: it turns off backslash interpretation (e.g. without it, read will treat a backslash at the end of an input line as a continuation marker).